# How to add IPs to a CentOS Server?

Tags: centos, ip, subnet

I wanted to know how to add the Prefix, the usable range & the subnet mask. I'm a completely new to this field so I would need step-by-step instructions. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Netizen

P.S. I've no control panel installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it permanently

Create a new file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1`

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.0.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
```

Then issue `ifup eth0:1`

If you just want to add an IP temporarily (or without persistence between reboots).

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0
```

The `/24` represents the netmask `255.255.255.0` in [CIDR notation](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php)

*Google first before asking on SF, your question is exceptionally well covered on the internet.*

Comment: Yup, Will google next time. Could you give me the commands to make that file, & to issue that. I'm extremely new to this & I want to do this permanently.

Comment: Open a text editor, paste and save. `nano` and `vi` are your command line friends.